# How to solve a boundary value problem of a Laplace equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $x,y$ are in the range $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 2,0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1$, I can use separation of variables to get $\frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial {x^2}}} + \frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial {y^2}}} = 0$ has a general solution of the form $\phi (x,y) = (A{e^{\lambda x}} + B{e^{ - \lambda x}})(C\cos \lambda y + D\sin \lambda y)$ which is periodic in $y$. But I cannot figure out how to decide those constants under given boundary conditions.

(a) $\phi  = 0$ when $y=0$ and $y=1$.

(b) $\phi  = 0$ when $x=0$.

How to consider problems like this? I really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just plug in the boundary values and see if you can choose the constants such that all conditions are fulfilled at the same time. In this case, $C = 0$ and $A = -B$ works.